# how to change folder location to save file - DJANGO FileSystemStorage

Tags: django, django-views, local-storage, django-file-upload, file-system-storage

so i want when i upload a file, the file will go to media/mp3 not media/txt. how to change save file location?

views.py:

```
def homepage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
    form = Audio_store(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
         handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['record'])
         return HttpResponseRedirect('mp3/')
return render(request, "homepage.html", {'form': form})
```

[image: folder]

[image: error]

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify [**`FileSystemStorage.location`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage.location)

```
def homepage(request):
    form = Audio_store()
    if request.method == "POST":
       form = Audio_store(request.POST, request.FILES)
       if form.is_valid():
          handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['record'])
          return HttpResponseRedirect('mp3/')
    return render(request, "homepage.html", {'form': form})
```

To use this you've to set **`MEDIA_ROOT`** inside your **settings.py** file because **`FileSystemStorage.location`** uses **`MEDIA_ROOT`** as default value.

Comment: MEDIA_URL = '/media/', MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'). like that?

Comment: Hello @Monana Yes, It's correct and let me know if you're facing some error

Comment: i was upload error, please check it

Comment: Hello @Monana please share text of error instead of images, [edit] your question and provide full error in text

Comment: i was update it, please check it

Comment: Hello @Monana you've provided image of error instead of image copy error text and add it inside your question

Comment: Hello @Monana check I've edited my answer